# session not getting value from one php value to another

Tags: php, session

I am trying to send value of a variable named "topic" from one php file to another php file ... there is no error in the code but the value of variable is not displaying in the other php file ...
please help ... thank you

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];

$to = $_POST['to'];

$from = $_POST['from'];

$subject = $_POST['subject'];

$topic = $_POST['topic'];

$message = "From: ".$name."\r\n";

$message .= $_POST['message'];

$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";

$headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";

$headers = "From:" . $from;


 session_start();

 $_SESSION['top'] = $topic;

 mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```

another php file is

```
  <?php 

  session_start();

 $topic = $_GET['top'];

 ?> 

   <h1><center>Meeting Invitation</center></h1>

   <form action="my.php" method="post">

      You are invited for the meeting on <?php echo $topic;?>

       proposed dates are :<br><br>

        Date &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Time<br>


        10 jan,2015 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 10.00 am<input type = "radio" name = "dat" <?php if 

    (isset($dat) && $dat=="val1") echo "checked";?> value = "val1" checked="true" ><br>

        12 feb,2015 &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 12.15 am<input type = "radio" name = "dat" <?php if 

   (isset($dat) && $dat=="val2") echo "checked";?> value = "val2" ><br><br>

        Proposed locations are :<br>

        Location 1 : &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Islamabad <input type = "radio" name = "location" <?php 

  if (isset($location) && $location=="val1") echo "checked";?>  value = "val1" checked="true" >               

 <br>

    Location 2 : &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Rawalpindi <input type = "radio" name = "location" <?php if      

   (isset($location) && $location=="val2") echo "checked";?>  value = "val2" ><br><br>

    Do you want travel facility ? &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

     <input type="checkbox" name="check_list1" value="yes"> <br><br>

    Do you want hotel facility ? &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;

        <input type="checkbox" name="check_list2" value="yes"> <br><br><br>

        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send Response">

        <input type="reset" >

   </form>

<?php 


 ?>
```

Comment: off topic, but your last `$headers` variable should be `$headers .=` (concatenated) and not `$headers =`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are using `$_GET` instead of `$_SESSION` in the second file.

Change

```
$topic = $_GET['top'];
```

to

```
$topic = $_SESSION['top'];
```

Comment: thank you ... i edit my code but its still not working

Comment: Are you calling `session_start()` *before* you send any output?

Comment: yes in the first php file i am calling session_start() before sending output and in the second php file i am also calling session_start() before getting value as mentioned in above code ..

Comment: Are you certain that `$_SESSION['top'];` is being set properly in the first script? Is `$_POST['topic']` coming through correctly? Try calling `print_r($_POST)` in the first script to make sure it is being submitted correctly.

Comment: Are there any additional details you can provide? Can you update your question with your current code as well as any additional code that may be relevant?